# How to import Python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry, this is definitely a duplicate, but I can't find the answer. I'm working in Python 3 and this is the structure of my app:

```
/home
  common.py
  australia/
    new-south-wales/
      fetch.py
```

I am in the `home/` directory, running `fetch.py`. How can I import functions from `common.py` in that script?

I've set up `fetch.py` as follows:

```
from common import writeFile
```

But I get the following error:

```
File "australia/new-south-wales/fetch.py", line 8, in <module>
    from common import writeFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
```

If I just do `python -c "from common import writeFile"` I don't see an error.

Shouldn't the interpreter [look in the current directory for modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)?

Comment: You're missing an `__init__.py` for your module. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

before import your directories that need to be imported must have file `__init__.py` in that folder

**#solution 1** (import in runtime)

To import a specific Python file at 'runtime' with a known name:

```
import os
import sys
script_dir = "/path/to/your/code/directory"

# Add the absolute directory  path containing your
# module to the Python path

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(script_dir))

import filename
```

**#solution 2**(add files to one of python libraries)

also as you have a common library for you can run

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
```

and see what directories you can put your code and use in every project.you can move your common package to one of this directories and treat it like a normal package.for example for common.py if you put it in one root directory of one of this directory you can import like  `import common`

**#solution 3**(use relative import)

```
# from two parent above current directory import common
# every dot for one parent directory
from ... import common
```

and then go to parent directory and run

```
python -m home.australia.new-south-wales.fetch
```

Comment: Thanks.This seems pretty inelegant - is there a better way to share common functions between scripts in different sub-directories? (Also, I guess you mean `__init__.py`?)

Comment: I've added an empty `__init__.py` file in `home/`, and I've added  `scriptpath = "../../common.py"` followed by `import common` in `fetch.py`. I still get an error trying to run `fetch.py` from `home/`.

Comment: yes i mean `__init__.py`;i use this way too;change scriptpath to `"../../"`

Comment: Thanks, changed as you suggest but still get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'`,

Comment: This also isn't PEP8-compliant - surely there must be a better way?

Comment: I also added another way that is PEP8-compliant

Comment: I also added another solution for relative imports

Answer (score 1):

From the description I'm assuming you're not running this as complete python package, just as separate files.

What you can do is use complete modules. This means adding empty `__init__.py` to directories with your code. You'll also have to change the name of `new-south-wales` to `new_south_wales`, since it needs to be a valid module name.

Assuming `home` is the name of your app, you should end up with:

```
home/
  __init__.py
  common.py
  australia/
    __init__.py
    new_south_wales/
      __init__.py
      fetch.py
```

Next, you'll need a startup script for your app - this means either something simple like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from australia.new_south_wales import fetch
fetch.your_main_function()
```

Or you can add a `setup.py` with a full package description. If you specify [entry points](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) and the script will be automatically created.

Now that you're starting your code in context of a package, your `fetch.py` can do:

```
from ..common import writeFile
```