# tensorflow_hub to pull BERT embedding on windows machine

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub, elmo

I would like to get BERT embedding using tensorflow hub. I found it very easy to get ELMO embedding and my steps are below. Could anyone explain how to get BERT embedding on a windows machine? I found [this](https://medium.com/@vineet.mundhra/loading-bert-with-tensorflow-hub-7f5a1c722565) but couldn't get it work on windows machine

1. https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/3 go to this link and then download.
2. Unzip it twice till you see "tfhub_module.pb", provide path of that folder to get embedding

   ```
       import tensorflow as tf
       import tensorflow_hub as hub

       elmo = hub.Module("C:/Users/nnnn/Desktop/BERT/elmo/3.tar/3", trainable=True)

       with tf.Session() as sess:
           sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
           abc1=sess.run(elmo(x, signature="default", as_dict=True)["default"])
   ```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
update 1

list of the problems that I am facing are below - I will add them one by one. This [page](https://github.com/vineetm/tfhub-bert/blob/master/bert_tfhub.ipynb) has the complete notebook from the same author.

1. when i try `import tokenization`, i get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tokenization'` How do i get rid of it? Do I need to download the `tokenization.py` and refer to it? Please clarify

==============update 2
I was able to get it work. The code with comments are as below

```
#manually copy paste code from https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/tokenization.py and create a file called C:\\Users\\nn\\Desktop\\BERT\\tokenization.py
#for some reason direct download doesn’t work

#https://github.com/vineetm/tfhub-bert/blob/master/bert_tfhub.ipynb 

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891069/how-to-import-python-file
import sys
import os

print (sys.path)


script_dir = "C:\\Users\\nn\\Desktop\\BERT"



# Add the absolute directory  path containing your
# module to the Python path

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(script_dir))

import tokenization





import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf

#download https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1 and unzip twice
def create_tokenizer(vocab_file='C:\\Users\\nn\\Desktop\\BERT\\bert_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12\\bert_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12~\\assets\\vocab.txt', do_lower_case=False):
    return tokenization.FullTokenizer(vocab_file=vocab_file, do_lower_case=do_lower_case)


tokenizer = create_tokenizer()


def convert_sentence_to_features(sentence, tokenizer, max_seq_len):
    tokens = ['[CLS]']
    tokens.extend(tokenizer.tokenize(sentence))
    if len(tokens) > max_seq_len-1:
        tokens = tokens[:max_seq_len-1]
    tokens.append('[SEP]')

    segment_ids = [0] * len(tokens)
    input_ids = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokens)
    input_mask = [1] * len(input_ids)

    #Zero Mask till seq_length
    zero_mask = [0] * (max_seq_len-len(tokens))
    input_ids.extend(zero_mask)
    input_mask.extend(zero_mask)
    segment_ids.extend(zero_mask)

    return input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids

def convert_sentences_to_features(sentences, tokenizer, max_seq_len=20):
    all_input_ids = []
    all_input_mask = []
    all_segment_ids = []

    for sentence in sentences:
        input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids = convert_sentence_to_features(sentence, tokenizer, max_seq_len)
        all_input_ids.append(input_ids)
        all_input_mask.append(input_mask)
        all_segment_ids.append(segment_ids)

    return all_input_ids, all_input_mask, all_segment_ids



#BERT_URL = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1'

BERT_URL ='C:\\Users\\nn\\Desktop\\BERT\\bert_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12\\bert_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12~'

module = hub.Module(BERT_URL)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


input_ids = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, None])
input_mask = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, None])
segment_ids = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, None])

bert_inputs = dict(
    input_ids=input_ids,
    input_mask=input_mask,
    segment_ids=segment_ids)

bert_outputs = module(bert_inputs, signature="tokens", as_dict=True)


sentences = ['New Delhi is the capital of India', 'The capital of India is Delhi']
input_ids_vals, input_mask_vals, segment_ids_vals = convert_sentences_to_features(sentences, tokenizer, 10)#max_seq_len parameter

out = sess.run(bert_outputs, feed_dict={input_ids: input_ids_vals, input_mask: input_mask_vals, segment_ids: segment_ids_vals})

out['sequence_output'].shape

out['pooled_output'].shape

out.keys()

type(out['pooled_output'])

x1=out['sequence_output'][0,:,:]
x2=out['sequence_output'][1,:,:]#Sentences length is 7, even if i add cls and sep tokens, the length is 9. max_seq_len parameter is 10, then why are the last row of x1 and x2 not same?
```

Comment: What was the error on your windows machine?

Comment: `import tokenization` works only if your program is inside bert directory. Which has to be cloned from https://github.com/google-research/bert

Comment: Also, seem contents below this is answer "==============update 2 I was able to get it work. The code with comments are as below", This can be posted as an answer

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/GeetDsa/BERTEmbeddings for embeddings