# tensorflow_hub to pull BERT embedding on windows machine - extending to albert

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

Recently I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58961467/tensorflow-hub-to-pull-bert-embedding-on-windows-machine) and tried to solve my problem. My questions are

1. is my approach correct?
2. My example sentences length are 7 and 6 respectively - `(['New Delhi is the capital of India', 'The capital of India is Delhi'])`, even if I add cls and sep tokens, the lengths are 9 and 8. max_seq_len parameter is 10, then why the last row of `x1` and `x2` are not the same?
3. How to get embedding when I have a paragraph of more than 2 sentences? do i have to pass one sentence at a time? But in such case wont i loose information as I am not passing all sentences  together?

   - I did some additional research and it seems that I can pass entire paragraph as a single sentence using `segment_ids` as 0 for all words in a paragraph. Is that correct?
4. how to get embedding for [ALBERT](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/albert)? I see that the ALBERT also has `tokenization.py` file. But I dont see `vocab.txt`. I see file `30k-clean.vocab`. Could i use `30k-clean.vocab` instead of `vocab.txt`?

Comment: Point no. 2: 1st sentence's  length is 7 and 2nd sentence's length is 6

Comment: i have fixed that part

Comment: 1. Your approach seems right

Comment: 2. Could you please check the tokenizations of sentence 1 and 2 using the tokenizer, this should reveal if there are additional word pieces in one of the sentences

Comment: Generally, word piece tokenization splits the words when words are not in vocabulary, this would create higher length of tokens than the number of inputs tokens

Comment: 3. You can pass both the sentences together, provided that the length of the paragraph after word piece tokenization does not exceed max_sequence length

Comment: 4. The vocab file for albert is in `./data/vocab.txt` directory. Provided you have got the albert code from: https://github.com/graykode/ALBERT-Pytorch

Comment: If you have got ALBERT from other sources, please mention the same :)

Comment: could you put your comments as an answer?

Comment: How do i do this? - `2. Could you please check the tokenizations of sentence 1 and 2 using the tokenizer, this should reveal if there are additional word pieces in one of the sentences ?`

Comment: `Generally, word piece tokenization splits the words when words are not in vocabulary, this would create higher length of tokens than the number of inputs tokens` - makes sense

Comment: `3. You can pass both the sentences together, provided that the length of the paragraph after word piece tokenization does not exceed max_sequence length` - makes sense

Comment: 4 i got albert from https://tfhub.dev/google/albert_base/2

Comment: could you also answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59182421/windows-spyder-invalid-syntax-error-while-running-py-file?

Comment: I checked the question '', seems other user has answered your question. But it also seems like you are trying to execute hugging-face pytorch  model from google's BERT ; Not sure if its just the name of directory that you have given. Let me know if the solution of other user does not work.

Answer (score 2):

@user2543622, you may refer to the official code [here](https://github.com/google-research/ALBERT/blob/master/run_classifier_with_tfhub.py#L144), in your case, you can do something like:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
albert_module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/albert_base/2", trainable=True)
print(albert_module.get_signature_names()) # should output ['tokens', 'tokenization_info', 'mlm']
# then 
tokenization_info = albert_module(signature="tokenization_info",
                                  as_dict=True)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  vocab_file, do_lower_case = sess.run([tokenization_info["vocab_file"],
                                        tokenization_info["do_lower_case"]])
print(vocab_file) # output b'/var/folders/v6/vnz79w0d2dn95fj0mtnqs27m0000gn/T/tfhub_modules/098d91f064a4f53dffc7633d00c3d8e87f3a4716/assets/30k-clean.model'
```

I guess this `vocab_file` is a binary [sentencepiece](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece) model file, so you should this one for tokenization as below, instead of using the 30k-clean.vocab.

```
# you still need the tokenization.py code to perform full tokenization
return tokenization.FullTokenizer(
  vocab_file=vocab_file, do_lower_case=do_lower_case,
  spm_model_file=FLAGS.spm_model_file)
```

If you only need the embedding matrix values, you take a look at the `albert_module.variable_map`, e.g.:

```
print(albert_module.variable_map['bert/embeddings/word_embeddings'])
# <tf.Variable 'module/bert/embeddings/word_embeddings:0' shape=(30000, 128) dtype=float32>
```

Comment: i dont want to connect to internet `https://tfhub.dev/google/albert_base/2` every time as it slows down the process. Thats why i developed above solution where i have downloaded model to my machine. Please check my approach

Comment: Right, I understand your concern, actually, it only downloads the model the first time, and later on, only use the URL as a key to retrieve the model on your disk instead of downloading from the internet. I've been using this feature for a while. I assume you have to download at least once to use that, is that right? You can even avoid downloading again if you have already downloaded the models before, just set `os.environ['TFHUB_CACHE_DIR'] = 'your model location'`

Comment: coudl you answer questions 2,3,4? or/and could you get embedding for those two sentences and past it here so that i can check them with the embeddings that i get?

Comment: I put a simple demo [here](https://gist.github.com/csarron/ed68a43e1716db855fbde02b53ecc1bb), not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: i got an error `spm_model_file b'C:\\Users\\nnn\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tfhub_modules\\098d91f064a4f53dffc7633d00c3d8e87f3a4716\\assets\\30k-clean.model'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-51ee36f48688>", line 20, in <module>
    spm_model_file=spm_model_file)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'spm_model_file'`. Do i have to download `tokenization.py`? Could you also look at my questons 1,2,3 and especially 2?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your approach seems right
2. Could you please check the tokenizations of sentence 1 and 2 using the tokenizer, this should reveal if there are additional word pieces in one of the sentences. This can be checked as below:

```
import tokenization
tokenizer = tokenization.FullTokenizer(vocab_file=<PATH to Vocab file>, do_lower_case=True)
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(example.text_a)
print(tokens)
```

This should give you word piece tokenized list, without `[CLS]` and `[SEP]` token.

Generally, word piece tokenization splits the words when words are not in vocabulary, this would create higher length of tokens than the number of inputs tokens.

3. You can pass both the sentences together, provided that the length of the paragraph after word piece tokenization does not exceed max_sequence length.
4. The vocab file for albert is in `./data/vocab.txt` directory. Provided you have got the albert code from: [here](https://github.com/graykode/ALBERT-Pytorch).
   In case, if  you have got the model from [tf-hub](https://tfhub.dev/google/albert_base/2), the file is `2/assets/30k-clean.vocab`

Comment: i got below results `tokens = tokenizer.tokenize('New Delhi is the capital of India')
print(tokens)
['New', 'Delhi', 'is', 'the', 'capital', 'of', 'India']

tokens = tokenizer.tokenize('The capital of India is Delhi')
print(tokens)
['The', 'capital', 'of', 'India', 'is', 'Delhi']` It seems that there are no extra words :( Therefore still not sure - why the last row of `x1` and `x2` are not the same?

Comment: Because, your 1st sentence has 7 words and 2nd sentence has 8 words!!

Comment: no, 2nd sentence has 6 words `['The', 'capital', 'of', 'India', 'is', 'Delhi']`

Comment: I changed max_seq_len parameter to 20 and still I am not getting same value for the last element. `convert_sentences_to_features(sentences, tokenizer, 20)#max_seq_len parameter`