# windows spyder invalid syntax error while running py file

Tags: windows, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to run the last example from the [page](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/08/comprehensive-guide-language-model-nlp-python-code/). I have cloned the repository in the directory `C:/Users/nn/Desktop/BERT/transformers-master`. I am on windows machine and using spyder IDE. Why i do get below error and how could i resolve it? How do i input the initial part of the poem?

```
import os

os.chdir('C:/Users/nn/Desktop/BERT/transformers-master/examples')
os.listdir()# It shows run_generation.py file

python run_generation.py \
    --model_type=gpt2 \
    --length=100 \
    --model_name_or_path=gpt2 \

python run_generation.py \
    --model_type=gpt2 \
    --length=100 \
    --model_name_or_path=gpt2 \
  File "<ipython-input-10-501d266b0e64>", line 1
    python run_generation.py \
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I went to command prompt and tried below

```
cd C:/Users/nn/Desktop/BERT/transformers-master/examples
python3 run_generation.py \--model_type=gpt2 \--length=100 \--model_name_or_path=gpt2 \--promt="Hello world"
```

nothing happens :(

when i try the same with python command i get an error as below :(

```
python run_generation.py \--model_type=gpt2 \--length=100 \--model_name_or_path=gpt2 \--promt="Hello world"
2019-12-04 11:23:36.345648: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_100.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_100.dll not found
2019-12-04 11:23:36.352875: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
usage: run_generation.py [-h] --model_type MODEL_TYPE --model_name_or_path
                         MODEL_NAME_OR_PATH [--prompt PROMPT]
                         [--padding_text PADDING_TEXT] [--xlm_lang XLM_LANG]
                         [--length LENGTH] [--num_samples NUM_SAMPLES]
                         [--temperature TEMPERATURE]
                         [--repetition_penalty REPETITION_PENALTY]
                         [--top_k TOP_K] [--top_p TOP_P] [--no_cuda]
                         [--seed SEED] [--stop_token STOP_TOKEN]
run_generation.py: error: the following arguments are required: --model_type, --model_name_or_path
```

***####update 2 ------------------***

I followed suggestions in the comments and it worked. It seems that the code downloads 3 files.

1. Can i copy those files manually so that I dont have to rely on downloading them every time in a temp folder?
2. Where should i store those files? which folder location? would it be `C:\Users\nnn\Desktop\BERT\transformers-master\examples` - same as `run_generation.py` file?

`abc`

```
C:\Users\nnn\Desktop\BERT\transformers-master\examples>python run_generation.py --model_type=gpt2 --length=100 --model_name_or_path=gpt2 --prompt="My job is"

2019-12-12 11:11:57.740810: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_100.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_100.dll not found
2019-12-12 11:11:57.748330: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
12/12/2019 11:12:01 - INFO - transformers.file_utils -   https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/gpt2-vocab.json not found in cache or force_download set to True, downloading to C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpt_29gyqi
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1042301/1042301 [00:00<00:00, 2275416.04B/s]
12/12/2019 11:12:02 - INFO - transformers.file_utils -   copying C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpt_29gyqi to cache at C:\Users\nnn\.cache\torch\transformers\f2808208f9bec2320371a9f5f891c184ae0b674ef866b79c58177067d15732dd.1512018be4ba4e8726e41b9145129dc30651ea4fec86aa61f4b9f40bf94eac71
12/12/2019 11:12:02 - INFO - transformers.file_utils -   creating metadata file for C:\Users\nnn\.cache\torch\transformers\f2808208f9bec2320371a9f5f891c184ae0b674ef866b79c58177067d15732dd.1512018be4ba4e8726e41b9145129dc30651ea4fec86aa61f4b9f40bf94eac71
12/12/2019 11:12:02 - INFO - transformers.file_utils -   removing temp file C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpt_29gyqi
12/12/2019 11:12:03 - INFO - transformers.file_utils -   https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/gpt2-merges.txt not found in cache or force_download set to True, downloading to C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj1_y4sn8
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 456318/456318 [00:00<00:00, 1456594.78B/s]
12/12/2019 11:12:03 - INFO - transformers.file_utils -   copying C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj1_y4sn8 to cache at C:\Users\nnn\.cache\torch\transformers\d629f792e430b3c76a1291bb2766b0a047e36fae0588f9dbc1ae51decdff691b.70bec105b4158ed9a1747fea67a43f5dee97855c64d62b6ec3742f4cfdb5feda
12/12/2019 11:12:03 - INFO - transformers.file_utils -   creating metadata file for C:\Users\nnn\.cache\torch\transformers\d629f792e430b3c76a1291bb2766b0a047e36fae0588f9dbc1ae51decdff691b.70bec105b4158ed9a1747fea67a43f5dee97855c64d62b6ec3742f4cfdb5feda
12/12/2019 11:12:03 - INFO - transformers.file_utils -   removing temp file C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj1_y4sn8
12/12/2019 11:12:03 - INFO - transformers.tokenization_utils -   loading file https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/gpt2-vocab.json from cache at C:\Users\nnn\.cache\torch\transformers\f2808208f9bec2320371a9f5f891c184ae0b674ef866b79c58177067d15732dd.1512018be4ba4e8726e41b9145129dc30651ea4fec86aa61f4b9f40bf94eac71
12/12/2019 11:12:03 - INFO - transformers.tokenization_utils -   loading file https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/gpt2-merges.txt from cache at C:\Users\nnn\.cache\torch\transformers\d629f792e430b3c76a1291bb2766b0a047e36fae0588f9dbc1ae51decdff691b.70bec105b4158ed9a1747fea67a43f5dee97855c64d62b6ec3742f4cfdb5feda
12/12/2019 11:12:04 - INFO - transformers.file_utils -   https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/gpt2-config.json not found in cache or force_download set to True, downloading to C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyxywrts1
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 176/176 [00:00<00:00, 17738.31B/s]
12/12/2019 11:12:04 - INFO - transformers.file_utils -   copying C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyxywrts1 to cache at C:\Users\nnn\.cache\torch\transformers\4be02c5697d91738003fb1685c9872f284166aa32e061576bbe6aaeb95649fcf.085d5f6a8e7812ea05ff0e6ed0645ab2e75d80387ad55c1ad9806ee70d272f80
12/12/2019 11:12:04 - INFO - transformers.file_utils -   creating metadata file for C:\Users\nnn\.cache\torch\transformers\4be02c5697d91738003fb1685c9872f284166aa32e061576bbe6aaeb95649fcf.085d5f6a8e7812ea05ff0e6ed0645ab2e75d80387ad55c1ad9806ee70d272f80
12/12/2019 11:12:04 - INFO - transformers.file_utils -   removing temp file C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyxywrts1
12/12/2019 11:12:04 - INFO - transformers.configuration_utils -   loading configuration file https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/gpt2-config.json from cache at C:\Users\nnn\.cache\torch\transformers\4be02c5697d91738003fb1685c9872f284166aa32e061576bbe6aaeb95649fcf.085d5f6a8e7812ea05ff0e6ed0645ab2e75d80387ad55c1ad9806ee70d272f80
12/12/2019 11:12:04 - INFO - transformers.configuration_utils -   Model config {
  "attn_pdrop": 0.1,
  "embd_pdrop": 0.1,
  "finetuning_task": null,
  "initializer_range": 0.02,
  "layer_norm_epsilon": 1e-05,
  "n_ctx": 1024,
  "n_embd": 768,
  "n_head": 12,
  "n_layer": 12,
  "n_positions": 1024,
  "num_labels": 1,
  "output_attentions": false,
  "output_hidden_states": false,
  "output_past": true,
  "pruned_heads": {},
  "resid_pdrop": 0.1,
  "summary_activation": null,
  "summary_first_dropout": 0.1,
  "summary_proj_to_labels": true,
  "summary_type": "cls_index",
  "summary_use_proj": true,
  "torchscript": false,
  "use_bfloat16": false,
  "vocab_size": 50257
}

12/12/2019 11:12:04 - INFO - transformers.file_utils -   https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/gpt2-pytorch_model.bin not found in cache or force_download set to True, downloading to C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpn8i9o_tm
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 548118077/548118077 [01:12<00:00, 7544610.26B/s]
12/12/2019 11:13:18 - INFO - transformers.file_utils -   copying C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpn8i9o_tm to cache at C:\Users\nnn\.cache\torch\transformers\4295d67f022061768f4adc386234dbdb781c814c39662dd1662221c309962c55.778cf36f5c4e5d94c8cd9cefcf2a580c8643570eb327f0d4a1f007fab2acbdf1
12/12/2019 11:13:24 - INFO - transformers.file_utils -   creating metadata file for C:\Users\nnn\.cache\torch\transformers\4295d67f022061768f4adc386234dbdb781c814c39662dd1662221c309962c55.778cf36f5c4e5d94c8cd9cefcf2a580c8643570eb327f0d4a1f007fab2acbdf1
12/12/2019 11:13:24 - INFO - transformers.file_utils -   removing temp file C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpn8i9o_tm
12/12/2019 11:13:24 - INFO - transformers.modeling_utils -   loading weights file https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/gpt2-pytorch_model.bin from cache at C:\Users\nnn\.cache\torch\transformers\4295d67f022061768f4adc386234dbdb781c814c39662dd1662221c309962c55.778cf36f5c4e5d94c8cd9cefcf2a580c8643570eb327f0d4a1f007fab2acbdf1
12/12/2019 11:13:32 - INFO - __main__ -   Namespace(device=device(type='cpu'), length=100, model_name_or_path='gpt2', model_type='gpt2', n_gpu=0, no_cuda=False, num_samples=1, padding_text='', prompt='My job is', repetition_penalty=1.0, seed=42, stop_token=None, temperature=1.0, top_k=0, top_p=0.9, xlm_lang='')
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [00:23<00:00,  2.49it/s]
 to know when it will change, it's up to you."

National Communications Director Alex Brynner said the Trump administration needs to help then-Secretary of State Rex Tillerson learn from him.

"The Cabinet, like any other government job, has to be attentive to the needs of an individual that might challenge his or her position," Brynner said. "This is especially true in times of renewed volatility."

Brynner said Tillerson has not "failed at vetting
```

Comment: Did you try to run the code with otherwise same params, but another prompt? I tried and it takes the 3 files from cache automatically.

Comment: i dont think running from another prompt would help if lets say i want to restart the machine and run command after that

Comment: I mean the --prompt option. But yes, the cache is not there forever and frankly, I don't have solution on that.

Comment: Well, looked back: /pytorch-transformers/transformers/file_utils.py has the file handling and cache. You should somehow hardcode the file location there to use same cached files or something. Hard to say, may not be an easy task.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the pre-requisites of the task:

> Installing PyTorch-Transformers on your Machine
>   Installing Pytorch-Transformers is pretty straightforward in Python. You can simply use pip install:

```
     pip install pytorch-transformers
```

> or if you are working on Colab:

```
     !pip install pytorch-transformers
```

> Since most of these models are GPU-heavy, I would suggest working with Google Colab for this part of the article.

Link to Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb#recent=true

The command syntax used in colab is little bit different, as you can observe from pip command above.

The example command most probably runs better with removal of \ characters (when on cmd) and having all command arguments on same line separated by space char only.

Command may require heavy calculation, so colab with syntax from example directly works in there.

---

**Edit:**

Now, looking back your code, there is an important typo:

use prompt with another p, not promt. Then you'd most probably be able to input the seed for the algorithm. I am testing this on my own computer and will soon comment if I find another issue.

---

**Edit2:**

My test took some time, now I am ready. I had to follow 3 Readme.md files to get the tutorial to work: one from the root folder, one below tranformers and lastly, the one from samples. Then running this command I got my first results:

```
  python pytorch-transformers/examples/run_generation.py --model_type=gpt2 --length=2 --model_name_or_path=gpt2 --prompt="My job is"
```

..and the computer thought a time and said quite well: "to know".

Comment: i have pytorch-transformers installed on my machine. I tried running the command without \ and it didnt work